A website with a different web framework per webpage possible?
Basically, I wanna make a website wherein each pages is built on a different web framework and I wanna know if it is somewhat possible.
Example: Website's Home Page is made through the Ruby on Rails framework and it has a navlink to the about page which is made through the Django web framework this time and it also has another navlink to the content page which is made in Laravel.
Plausible? In my thinking, at some point it theoretically can be plausible but only because I'm thinking that most of these frameworks eventually mold our code into simple vanilla HTML/CSS/JS webpages which we can load into even in a different web framework with just anchor links here and there but I also realized that most, if not all web frameworks need to rely on either a localhost/debug/hosted web server to run their code which means we can't easily go to a webpage without executing server host commands for specific web frameworks which led me to the idea that maybe we can just make the navlinks link to separate links of the hosted webpage of a framework but it wouldn't be webpages of the original website anymore. It'd be a website linking to other different websites. Because of this, I'm wondering if there is actually another way to properly execute this.

Yes, it's trivially possible (and commonly done.) The web server just needs to be set up to serve different backends depending on the URL path.

Yes, this is definitely possible. You have at least a webserver at play which can specify what and how to handle a request. You could create virtual hosts, or you could create a wrapper project that would control which one handles what.
